# Distributing multiplication over double sumation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is the following derivation correct? My intuition is quite confused here.

$\sum \limits_{x \in X} \sum \limits_{y \in f(x)} \frac{xy}{\sum \limits_{z \in g(y)}z} = \frac{(\sum \limits_{x \in X} x)(\sum \limits_{x \in X} \sum \limits_{y \in f(x)} y)}{\sum \limits_{x \in X} \sum \limits_{y \in f(X)} \sum \limits_{z \in g(y)} z}$

I know something like this is allowed by the distributive law, but I feel like I'm making some kind of mistake here.

Comment: Is $ab + cd = (a+c)(b+d)$? Also that is **triple** summation. You should consider a simpler case, like $$\sum_{x\in X}\sum_{y\in Y} (xy)$$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Doesn't the multiplication rule for finite sums say that $(\sum \limits_{x \in X} x)(\sum \limits_{y \in Y} y) = \sum \limits_{x \in X} \sum \limits_{y \in Y} (xy)$?

Comment: My mistake. You only have $\sum(x N) = N \sum(x)$ if $N$ is independent of $x$. So you can only get $$\sum_{x\in X}(x\sum_{y\in f(x)}({y\over\sum_{z\in g(y)}(z)}))$$ at most. $$\sum_{x\in X}(x)\sum_{x\in X}(\sum_{y\in f(x)}(y))=\sum_{x\in X}(\sum_{y\in f(x)}(\sum_{x\in X}(xy)))$$ instead of $$\sum_{x\in X}(\sum_{y\in f(x)}(xy))$$.